# Passing byte[] from Unity C# to Android Java without copying (pointer?)

Tags: java, c#, android, unity-game-engine, java-native-interface

Is it possible to pass a byte[] from Unity C# to Android Java without copying it? In other words transferring it as fast as possible, possibly as a pointer.

The use case is sending a byte[] with a length of 1920x1080 (derived from [.GetRawTextureData](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetRawTextureData.html), 30 times per second. Currently I am passing the byte[] as a parameter in a `AndroidJavaObject` method call but it is too slow (100 milliseconds per call). Any ideas?

Comment: When you say _pass_, do you mean between two separate processes?

Comment: @Martin now I am not sure what do you mean by two separate processes. The environment is a Unity game that talks to an Android plugin via calls to ```AndroidJavaObject```.

Comment: In general afaik the [`NativeArray<T>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.html) is more used for passing stuff between Unity's Job-System and the main thread .. not for passing data between plugins and the main app

Comment: @derHugo I was thinking about using ```NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeReadOnlyPtr``` (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.NativeArrayUnsafeUtility.GetUnsafeReadOnlyPtr.html) but didn't find a way to hook it into Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer per see but I have realized that sending 8MB of `sbytes` through JNI takes only ~ 7 milliseconds (I didn't profile it correctly at the first try). It is a lot faster to send `sbytes` than `bytes` because `bytes` have to be converted to `bytes` anyway (C# bytes are not signed so they have to be converted because Java uses signed bytes) and the implementation of conversion is very slow. Furthermore, you can work directly in `sbytes`, which further improves performance and reduces the need to work with references.